# How to find the third coordinate of an equilateral triangle?

Tags: matlab, coordinates, formulas

If I have two points say A(x,y) & B(p,q), how can I find the coordinates of the third point on both sides of AB?

I have the formula for one side, but that cannot give the other one..

Need the formula for coordinates of third point on each sides.

Comment: For the future, it should be noted that this isn't really a programming question; it's a math question. The Math site would have been a more appropriate place to post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about maths/geometry.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) `R` is:

```
A = [0 0];
B = [0 1];
AB = B-A;
theta = deg2rad(60);
R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
C = A + AB*R';
X = [A;B;C; A];
plot(X(:, 1), X(:, 2));
axis equal
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the result on one side then it's easy to find the symmetrical point.

Let's say your result for the third point is C(r, s). You need to find D(t, w), the symmetrical point of C, with respect to the segment AB.

For this we consider the middle of AB: M(u, v) = (A(x, y) + B(p, q)) / 2;

We have the following equation: M(u, v) = (D(t, w) + C(r, s))/2.

We get D(t, w) = 2 * M(u, v) - C(r, s).
We further get: D(t, w) = A(x, y) + B(p, q) - C(r, s).